# Change font color on every new "append" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, append

I have a page where I am using the append function to add a new line of text (".newText") every 5 seconds.

This is what I have currently:

```
    var fontColors

    var randomColor

    $(function(){

    fontColors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet','pink']

    randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)]

    $('.newText').css({
            'color':randomColor

          })

    $('.newText').append('<p>original line of text</p>')

    setInterval(function(){ 
          $('.newText').append('<p>this text is added every 5 seconds</p>')
         randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)]
          $('.newText').css({
          'color':randomColor
          })
        }, 5000)
  })
  })
```

So right now it is changing the color of all of the text on the screen every 5 seconds (obviously). I would like for each new line to have a different color, but I do not want the colors of the previously appended lines of text to be changed.

Comment: Create a `<p>` element, add CSS to it, and then add it to the `newText` element, instead of changing the CSS of the `newText` element itself.

Comment: so add it to the p element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Instead of adding the color to your `.newText`, added to the newly appended line.

```js
var fontColors;
var randomColor;

$(function(){
    fontColors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet','pink']

    randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)]

    $('.newText').css({'color':randomColor});

    $('.newText').append('<p>original line of text</p>');

    setInterval(function(){ 
          var newLine = $('<p>this text is added every 5 seconds</p>');
          $('.newText').append(newLine)
         randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)]
          $(newLine).css({
          'color':randomColor
          })
        }, 5000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="newText"></span>
```

**UPDATE**

Incase someone would be looking for a pure `JS` solution, the following code should do the trick.

```js
let fontColors;
let randomColor;

function addNewText() {
  // Set all possible font colors.
  fontColors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet','pink'];
  
  // Generate a random number, which will represent a font color.
  randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)]
  
  // Set a new line.
  const container = document.querySelector('.newText');
  const newLine = document.createElement('p');
  newLine.textContent = 'original line of text';
  container.append(newLine);
  
  // Now set an interval, in which we will be adding new lines every
  // certain amount of time.
  setInterval( () => {
    const newLine = document.createElement('p');
    newLine.textContent = 'this text is added every 5 seconds';
    randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)];
    newLine.style.color = randomColor;
    container.append(newLine);
  }, 5000);
  
};

addNewText();
```

```html
<span class="newText"></span>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add inline css to your `p` tag when you append it like so:

```
$('.newText').append('<p style="color: ' + randomColor + '">this text is added every 5 seconds</p>')
```

See working example below:

```js
var fontColors
var randomColor

$(function() {
  fontColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'pink']
  randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)]
  
  $('.newText').append('<p style="color: ' + randomColor + '">original line of text</p>')

  setInterval(function() {
    randomColor = fontColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontColors.length)]
    $('.newText').append('<p style="color: ' + randomColor + '">this text is added every 5 seconds</p>')
  }, 5000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="newText"></div>
```

Comment: @eviero no worries, glad to help